# Instrument panel display broken, cheapest way to access information?

Tags: repair, mercedes-benz, instrument-cluster

The LCD panel of my Mercedes Benz A140 recently broke down and is impossible to read now:

[image]

Since this is such an old car, I don't want to spend money on expensive repairs, e.g. [sending the instrument cluster to a specialist](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/77828/34460).

I've identified the part number of the IC (A1685404011) and think I would be able to replace it on my own if I ordered a used one, but apparently one needs [specialist equipment to configure them for a specific vehicle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/77828/34460). Are the drawbacks of not doing this significant?

If one can read the information directly by connecting a reader to some ECU, I wouldn't mind doing this either, if it's the cheapest way. And I'm open to any other suggestions.

**What is the most affordable way of accessing the information usually displayed by this LCD panel (odometer, errors, maybe more?)?**

Comment: Yours looks like a simple connection issue. May be worth just opening the cluster up for cleaning / checking of the connection of the display.

Comment: @narkeleptk thanks, that's a good tip. I'll definitely try that.